# What is The name of a JSON feature that uses a reference method to prevent duplicate data?

Tags: c#, json, database, performance

I mean a JSON feature that uses a reference method to reduce data size ...
This is my homework in c# programming...
Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1):

It's not a feature of JSON - it's not part of the JSON spec at all, actually. The techniques used to add metadata to JSON, such as object-references, comments, and type information are all JSON extensions - usually using a prefixed property name.

There is no single name for those techniques either.

In Json.NET (aka `Newtonsoft.Json`) the API is `JsonSerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All`, as documented here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm

But other JSON libraries have their own interfaces for controlling this behaviour - and it is not standard between implementations.

Comment: @SaeedPashaZanussi It doesn't have a name - that's my point. If your homework says it has a name then your professor is mistaken.

Comment: I'm sorry...It's my mistake...I think its a feature or method related to recursive behavior of serializer!...Please help me...I need it's name!